# How to set an Odoo docker container using existing PostgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-15

I have **bare-metal** PostgreSQL server with **ip = 192.168.33.12** that i want to use with **Odoo**.

And I want to run Odoo in Docker and have some kind of persistence.

So, I wan to connect dockered **Odoo** with my **PostgreSQL** server.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:15.0
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons

volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
```

On Docker server I have created several directories:

```
~/odoo/config
~/odoo/addons
```

**docker-compose.yml** is in **~/odoo/**.

Refers to this guide [odoo - Official Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/) i got **odoo.conf** in "**~/odoo/config**"  that contains this:

```
[options]

addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo

admin_passwd = such_a_strong_password
db_host = 192.168.33.12
db_port = 5432
db_user = odooadmin
db_password = one_more_pass
dbfilter = ^odoo-docker-host-0.*$
db_maxconn = 64
```

So, after running

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I can see in Docker logs this entry:

```
Database connection failure: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution!

My config is ok.
The problem was in PostgreSQL server network configuration.

We need tu put this in **postgresql.conf**:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

And in **pg_hba.conf**:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

or better

```
host    all             all             ip_of_odoo_server       trust
```

Now everything  works fine.

Answer (score 0):

well, your docker-compose file is missing the db configurations an example [an example could be there](https://github.com/minhng92/odoo-15-docker-compose/blob/3cf888ae511249e15a60cc9d6e86f211d1254889/docker-compose.yml#L3). in your case your file could go as following:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    user: root
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo15@2021      
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    restart: always             # run as a service
    volumes:
        - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    image: odoo:15.0
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons

volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
```

Comment: I don't want to use Dockered PostgreSQL. 
I already have PosrgreSQL server installed on another VM and I want ot use it.